# Append data to numpy string

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

for some reason I can't append data to a numpy string.

```
for b in range(len(aUnique)):
    temp = aUnique[b]
    print(temp)
    numpy.append(sGewiss, temp)
    #RawData.cell(row=b+1, column=1).value = temp

print(sGewiss)
```

When I print "temp" I can see the right values so the loop is working correctly but when I print the array "sGewiss" I cannot see the new values added but only the old [66830 72312 72812].

Am I using the parameters wrong? Is there a dimension issue I am not aware of?

Thank you

I tried to add around 100 numbers to my array "sGweiss" which contains only 3 values.
I was expecting an array containing the starting 3 elements plus the new 100 elements

Comment: the NumPy [`append`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.append.html) method does not work "in-place" on the array that you pass it, i.e., it will not change `sGewiss` but will instead return a new array that is `sGewiss` appended with `temp`. You therefore have to store the return value, e.g., `sGewiss = np.append(sGewiss, temp)`.

Comment: this kind of iterative appending is ok with list, but not with arrays.  The 'numpy string' in the subject line does not make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use :

```
    sGewiss = numpy.append(sGewiss, temp)
```

This is because NumPy append function creates a new NumPy array and returns the desired output. It does not change the input array in place.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer.

sGewiss is a numpy list. If i use "sGewiss.append(temp)" i get an attribute error.

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: I updated my answer. that should work.